# Is it possible to specify a string consisting of a number of `^` characters for scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

In a C-`scanf` format, how do I specify, that I want a character `^`?

`"%[^]"` does not work with GNU `scanf`, because `^` at start has the negation meaning.

Comment: [`scanf("%[^]\001-\\_-\377]", s`](https://godbolt.org/z/n4r76M5bx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> scanf is it possible to specify a string consisting of a number of `^` characters?

Doing a simple `%[^]` is impossible.

The `%[^]` is actually invalid - the initial `[` is not closed. A `%[^]]` is interpreted as all characters except `]`.

Assuming `%[^]` would be valid, then it would present an ambiguity: `%[^]]` could be interpreted as a string consisting only from `^` followed by a `]`. Or imagine like `$[^]abc]`. I believe the ability to scan strings only consisting of `^` was sacrificed to give `^` its functionality, which makes a reasonable sacrifice.

To solve the problem in practice, do not use `scanf` and write it yourself. Or you could do something like `"%[\01^]` - scan also something else that will not be in the input, like `0x01` byte.

From [C99 7.19.6.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.2) (and [this pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)) (emphasis mine):

> `[`
>
> [...]
>
> The conversion specifier includes all subsequent characters in the format string, up to and including the matching right bracket (`]`).  The characters between the brackets (the scan list) compose the scanset, unless the character after the left bracket is a circumflex (^), in which case the scanset contains all characters that do not appear in the scanlist between the circumflex and the right bracket. If the conversion specifier begins with `[]` or `[^]`, **the right bracket character is in the scanlist** and **the next following** right bracket character is the matching right bracket that ends the specification; otherwise the first following right bracket character is the one that ends the specification. [...]

So if the conversion is `%[]` or `%[^]` then the `]` is in the scanlist, and *the next* `]` will end the scanlist.

As a workaround, you can specify in the scanlist `^` negation of all characters except `^`, effectively scanning only for `^` - `%[^^]`.